# Get h2 compatibility mode of current connection

Tags: h2

In H2 I can [set the compatibility mode for a connection](https://www.h2database.com/html/commands.html#set_mode):

```
SET MODE DB2;
```

Is there a way to query the mode like:

```
GET MODE;
```

For the current schema I can do `select schema()` but `select mode()` will not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With H2 1.*.* use

```sql
SELECT `VALUE` FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SETTINGS WHERE NAME = 'MODE';
```

With H2 2.*.* use

```sql
SELECT SETTING_VALUE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SETTINGS WHERE SETTING_NAME = 'MODE';
```

Use upper-case names of tables and columns in these queries for more safety, H2 has really weird settings for case conversion and sensitivity and some applications may enable them.

If old information schema was enabled in H2 2.*.* with a special setting or because old driver was used for remote connection to a new server, use variant for H2 1.*.*.

Comment: Thanks that works. I guess the information_schema is the only option to get that value. But it's sufficient for me.

Comment: Yes, there are no other ways. BTW, unrelated `SCHEMA()` function mentioned in your question is deprecated since H2 2.0.202, normally you should use standard-compliant `CURRENT_SCHEMA` (without parentheses) instead of it: https://h2database.com/html/functions.html#current_schema Also you can get schema name from JDBC Connection: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getSchema--